# Using directive for basic types like C++ typedef

Tags: c#

I[m trying to mimic a C++ typedef on C# using the using clause:

```
using MyString = System.String;
using MyInt = System.Int32;
using MyBool = System.Boolean;
using MyFloat = float;
```

It works for all types, except for the float type, as it is a basic type.

Is there a way to do something similar to C++ ?

```
typedef float MyFloat;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using MyFloat = System.Single;
```

References:

- [MSDN - Built-In Types Table (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds)